# Present participle of 'feel' and change in meaning

Tags: present-continuous, present-participles, present-simple

"I **feel** lucky"

"I am **feeling** lucky."

Do both sentences convey same meaning?I have read that emotive verbs are not used in participle form on account of their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these have similar meaning.  The progressive form of the emotive verb implies an *immediacy*, as if it's happening right now:

> A:  Hey, you're all lit up. What's going on?
>   B: I'm **feeling happy**, that's all.

It can also imply that is likely to change.

> I'm **feeling** that this stock is going to take off, so we should buy now.

The simple present means much the same thing, but it *can* imply something that happens regularly or repeatedly.

> A: Why are you looking down?
>   B: It's nothing.  I just always **feel sad** on the first day of autumn.

Answer (score 0):

Progressive/continuous forms of verbs are sometimes used to create a "background" for another action.

> I feel lucky, so I'll go ahead and place my bet (I didn't feel lucky, or think about how I was feeling, until I started saying this sentence).
>
> I am feeling lucky, so I'll go ahead and place my bet (My lucky feeling was something that started previously, or that I had recognized earlier, and is still in progress).

The difference in meaning is when the action started or was recognized.